# Siteminder injected custom header not found by ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, siteminder

I have a ASP.NET MVC website that is protected by Siteminder. After authentication. Siteminder injects custom header values and redirects to my MVc website. Here I am trying to parse the header in the Application_AuthenticateRequest method in the Global.asax.cs

```
 //Logging incoming request to check header for debug purposes
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new ApplicationException("Begin Request. \n REQUEST HEADER =" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.ToString() + " \n"));

        }

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
            {
                var smcred = ParseAuthorizationHeader(HttpContext.Current.Request);
                if (smcred.Username != null)
                {
                    if (Membership.ValidateUser(smcred.Username, null))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(smcred.Username, false);
                        var identity = new GenericIdentity(smcred.Username);
                        string[] roles = null;// Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(smcred.SMUser);
                        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

                        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    }
                }   
            } 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the Authorization header and creates user credentials
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        protected virtual SiteminderCredentials ParseAuthorizationHeader(HttpRequest request)
        {
            string authHeader = null;
            var smcredential = new SiteminderCredentials();
            var auth = request.Headers.Keys; //request.ServerVariables.Keys;

            foreach (string LstrKey in auth)
            {
                switch (LstrKey.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "USER":
                        smcredential.Username = request.Headers[LstrKey].ToString();
                }
            }


                return smcredential;


        }
```

SiteminderCredentials.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PerceptorWeb.Models
{
    public class SiteminderCredentials
    {

            public string Username;
            public string FirstName;
            public string LastName;
            public string EmailAddr;


    }
}
```

I installed advanced logging on IIS and I see that the custom header information is coming through fine from Siteminder to my IIS hosted site. But when my authenticate_request tries to parse the header none of those custom values are to be found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code which tries to parse out the custom headers!

Comment: I believe custom HTTP headers are inserted by SiteMinder web agent, which is an ISAPI filter sitting on your IIS server.  So, the traffic coming to IIS from outside is irrelevant.  You may want to talk to your SM admin guys and configure the agent on your server to inject the headers.  By default, it is the HTTP_SM_USER, but the header name can be customized.

https://enable.ca.com/answers/us/CA-SiteMinder/12.51-CA-SiteMinder/guide/CASiteMinder_Web_Agent_Configuration_Guide_1251/256659?parameters=&q=RGlyZWN0b3J5IGFzIGEgU2Vzc2lvbiBTdG9yZQ==